# Where do I put html bold tags in this php code sample?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, escaping

I need to have the word "Located:" in bold but can't figure out where to put the tags so they don't either print or break the code.

Read other threads here, put the bold tags around Located: but they just print. Tried moving the tags but it breaks the code.

```
/* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma 
*/
$tags_list = get_the_tag_list( '', esc_html__( ', ', 'vogue' ) );
if ( $tags_list ) {
    printf( '<br /><br /><span class="tags-links">' . esc_html__( '<b>Located:</b> %1$s', 'vogue' ) . '</span>', $tags_list ); // WPCS: XSS OK
}
```

Comment: Move the whole located part out of the esc_html, so that the only thing being run through the esc_html is the `%1$s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`esc_html` will escape any HTML you give it, so don't put the HTML in. Simple enough! You're using `esc_html__` and not just `esc_html` so I assume localization is important to you.

```
$tags_list = get_the_tag_list( '', esc_html__( ', ', 'vogue' ) );
if ( $tags_list ) {
    printf(
        '<br /><br /><span class="tags-links"><b>%s</b>%s</span>',
        __( 'Located:', 'vogue' ),
        $tags_list
    );
}
```

`printf` will replace each `%s` with a string representation of the argument, so all I've done is moved the translation of "Located:" into a separate argument. I'm not sure what you were going for with `%1$s` so I took it out and replaced it with a standard `%s`.

Comment: Thanks, getting closer. I know nothing about code, I got the code from Wordpress to put in my theme's functions.php file but they don't like answering PHP questions. Your solution did make the word bold, but now it's showing the link to the tag rather than  making the tag itself into a link. Like this: Located:(a href="https://tejadadesign.com/tag/w/" rel="tag")W(/a)  (I used parentheses rather than than the angle brackets.) Page is here: https://tejadadesign.com/category/home_decor/

Comment: So then the question becomes, "why are you escaping HTML at all?" :)

Comment: I'm not super familiar with Wordpress, so I didn't know that `get_the_tag_list` was returning HTML already. No need to use `esc_html` or variants on it. Answer has been updated.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. "Why are you escaping HTML at all?" I have no idea, I didn't write the code and really know nothing about coding or PHP. But thanks for your help. This page was just a test on my personal website, I will be building a WP site for a client using a different theme, so that will get interesting considering the entire code was written for the theme currently on MY site. Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help, please mark accepted if it answered your question. You might want to find some tutorials on this stuff before you go ahead "building a WP site for a client." Knowing about things like escaping HTML is critical; if you don't get it right you'll just be painting a target on your website saying "hack me!"

Comment: I've been making websites for 25 years, but do not get involved in the coding end. When I went to school it was still all HTML. With Wordpress I normally don't need to change anything, this was unusual. But thanks for the warning. I'm curious if the escaping HTML has something to do with the theme. I'm assuming the theme author put that in the code as I don't imagine WP Support would have written that specifically for me.

Comment: When writing a theme that's properly localized, the translations functions (like `esc_html__`) will pull translations for the language in question from a messages file. Since the theme author may not have written those messages files, it's safer to escape any HTML in them. Otherwise a compromised messages file could including things like JavaScript code to do malicious things.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($tags_list ) {
    printf(
        '<br /><br /><span class="tags-links"><b>Located:</b> ' . esc_html__('%1$s', 'vogue' ) . '</span>',
        $tags_list
    ); // WPCS: XSS OK
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that completely deleted the Wordpress entry footer content on the webpage.